# ¿Como usar swagger en github?

Tags: java, spring, github, swagger

Estaba creando un archivo *yml* desde la página propia de swagger, se ve todo como se debería ver:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo he subido a github, esperaba verlo de la misma manera, pero me encuentro con lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si me falta alguna configuración o algo en el proyecto. El **proyecto** es de **Spring**, con **java 11**, y la dependencia que he utilizado para comentar también el proyecto es la siguiente:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.20</version>
        </dependency>
```

La ubicación del archivo es dentro de la carpeta de **resources**.

Comment: Qué es exactamente lo que esperas que se vea?

Comment: Espero que se vea como en la primera imagen a la derecha.

Comment: En GIthub estás viendo el código fuente. La primera imagen muestra algo que swagger genera cuando despliegas tu aplicación (o en el editor específico); en github no estás desplegando nada y github no va a generar algo a partir de tu archivo de definición.

Comment: Entonces github no puede reconocer estos documentos? Sé que gitlab lo hace.

Comment: GitHub no tiene un visualizador específico que interprete los yaml y genere esa representación. Así es.

Comment: Ah... Porras, una pena... Es bueno saberlo. Gracias!